# Click outside should hide the div not when is child element of div are clicked?

Tags: jquery

I have a div inside it there is a jquery calendar control, having one dropdown for month.I want it to hide when clicked outside. The thing happening is when I click outside it is perfectly hiding out but it hide out even when I select something from dropdown box.

I have try this -

```
 $(document).mouseup(function (e) {
    var container = new Array();
    container.push($('.CalendardivTSFrom'));
    container.push($('.CalendarEditdiv1'));
    container.push($('.CalendarEditdiv'));

    $.each(container, function (key, value)
    {
        if (!$(value).is(e.target))
        {
            e.stopPropagation();
            $(value).hide();
        }
    });
});
```

when div's child element(dropdown) have a click then it should not hide that why I have used e.stopPropagation().

Please Help.

Thanks

Comment: Could you setup a JSFiddle demonstrating the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.. As long as you click within the wrapper, it won't hide the div.

```
$(document).on('click', function (e) {
    if ($('.CalendardivTSFrom').length > 0) {
        var elemDontClose = $('.CalendardivTSFrom'); // wrapper div i guess?!
        var rect = elemDontClose.get(0).getBoundingClientRect();
        var isClickWithinElement = (
            (e.clientX >= rect.left) &&
            (e.clientX <= rect.right) &&
            (e.clientY >= rect.top) &&
            (e.clientY <= rect.bottom)
        );

        if (!isClickWithinElement)
            HideDiv();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks but now it is not hiding when clicked outside

Comment: Ok, did you change the HideDiv(); method with your hide method? Is the var elemDontClose initialized as the wrapper? I cannot analyze your html as you did not supply it.

Comment: Besides i use the exact same code except for the wrapper div.. It works like a charm.